# Do you need to have separate meaty and miky glasses?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk, utensil

Is there any reason whatsoever to use different glasses, i.e., for hot milk beverages, and glasses used for a meaty table, as opposed to just washing them in between?